# Talend error while calling a context variables

Tags: talend

In a JOB TALEND I'm trying to call a context variable which is

```
context.d_end = TalendDate.getDate("YYYYMMDD")
```

to my SQL query :

```
TO_DATE('"+context.d_end +"','YYYYMMDD')
```

but I get this error

> ora-01841: l'année (complète) doit être comprise entre -4713 et +9999 et être différente de 0

Can someone help please?

Comment: Are you sure that context.d_end is initialized when used in your DB component ? Looks like it is not. Syntax seems correct

Comment: @Corentin what do you mean by initialized ? 

i go to context i added a variable d_end which has a string value TalendDate.getDate("YYYYMMDD")

than i go to my toraclerow and call it here 
TO_DATE('"+context.d_end +"','YYYYMMDD')

Comment: @corentin here is my two variable 
d_begin  string  20210601
d_end     string  TalendDate.getDate("YYYYMMDD") 
than i call them in this querry in toraclerow  
delete ICTPART_FACTU
where date_doc>=TO_DATE('" +context.d_begin+"','YYYYMMDD')
    and TRUNC(date_doc,'MONTH')<=TRUNC(TO_DATE('" +context.d_end+"','YYYYMMDD'),'MONTH') 

i got the error mentioned in top of speach

Comment: you have to initialize variable at runtime. Add a tJava prior to your dbinput, with context.d_end=TalendDate.getdate("yyyymmdd");